# Swift Manually Save Location Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, location

I want save manually location on map.I am tap on map and printing manually location. But my code(savemyadress) save current location. How should I edit code. Thanks

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import Firebase
class MapViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
@IBOutlet weak var saveButton : UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet var tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer!
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var ref: DatabaseReference!
var adres: Adresler!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ref = Database.database().reference()    
}
   
     func savemyadress(){
   
    let sender = self.tapGesture
    //if sender!.state == .ended{
        let locationInView = sender!.location(in: mapView)
        let tappedCoordinate = mapView.convert(locationInView, toCoordinateFrom: mapView)
    let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: tappedCoordinate, latitudinalMeters: 400, longitudinalMeters: 400)
    mapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)

        let userRef = self.ref.child("locations").child("Address")
        let coordinate = tappedCoordinate
        let adres = Adresler(latitude: coordinate.latitude , longitude: coordinate.longitude)
        let Locations = userRef.childByAutoId()
        let adresRef = Locations
        adresRef.setValue(adres.toDictionary())    
     //}  
}
      @IBAction func tapGesture(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
      if sender.state == .ended{
      let locationInView = sender.location(in: mapView)
      let tappedCoordinate = mapView.convert(locationInView, toCoordinateFrom:mapView)
  print(tappedCoordinate.latitude, tappedCoordinate.longitude)
  }}}
          extension MapViewController : CLLocationManagerDelegate {
 func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
           let location = locations.last! as CLLocation
           let currentLocation = location.coordinate
           let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: currentLocation, latitudinalMeters: 400, longitudinalMeters: 400)
    mapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { placemarks, error in
        guard let placemark = placemarks?.last else {
            let errorString = error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unexpected Error"
            return}
```

}
}
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
print("error:: (error)")}}

**UPDATE**

```
    @IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Address", message: "Save address", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default, handler: { [self]action in
        savemyadress()
        
        _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    
        }))
    
    self.present(alert, animated: true)
```

Comment: It's not clear where you're calling `savemyadress`. But, you already have the `tapGesture` to get the location on the map. Can you figure out how to call `savemyadress` and pass the location as a parameter?

Comment: My mistake. I updated code.

Comment: You need to store `tappedCoordinate` in a property so that you can use it instead of `locatiinManager.locatiin` in `savemyaddress`

Comment: I edited the code(savemyadress). This time when I click and save the selected area, its saving a different area around the selected area.